# Oracle - Which columns do I create index for select ... where s1 = 'xxx' and (s2 = 'xxx' or (s2 = 'xxx' and s3 = 'xxx'))?

Tags: database, oracle, relational-database

I have below SQL running frequently on `table_1`:

```
select * from table_1 where
s_1 = 'xxx' and
(s_2 = 'xxx' or (s_2 = 'xxx' and s_3 = 'xxx'));
```

If I create index on `table_1` to speed up select, which columns should I create on?

If the SQL is

```
select * from table_1 where
s_1 = 'xxx' and s_2 = 'xxx';
```

Index should add on `<s_1, s_2>`, but how about `or` operator?

I'm not looking for the SQL of create index. I'm looking for an explain of how we create index for such use case.

Comment: Is this about mysql or oracle? Can't be both and the syntax is different between them.

Comment: @SloanThrasher thanks for correction! I will update question.

Comment: There are more differences than just syntax. Tag your question correctly.

Comment: @SloanThrasher done, I limit this to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing which column or combination of columns to create an index on is not an exact science because there are many different factors to consider in each case, including but not limited to:

- query performance vs. insert/update/delete performance
- which columns are often queried together
- how big the data in the candidate columns are
- data volume and expected growth
- data uniqueness and skew
- Oracle version

Any advice saying you "should" create any particular index should be suspect, depending on how much knowledge the advice-giver knows about your particular situation.

```
select * from table_1 where
s_1 = 'xxx' and
(s_2 = 'xxx' or (s_2 = 'xxx' and s_3 = 'xxx'));
```

A query like this *might* take advantage of an index on `(s_1)`, but it depends partly on how selective the data in `s_1` is (i.e. how unique). If this query is executed very frequently you might consider a *covering index*, e.g. on (`s_1, s_2, s_3`) which would allow the optimizer to find all rows based on a simple index scan.

```
select * from table_1 where
s_1 = 'xxx' and s_2 = 'xxx';
```

A query like this *might* take advantage of an index on `(s_1, s_2)` but that is not necessarily the best index.

Some alternative indexing strategies considering this query include:

- `(s_2, s_1)`
- `(s_1)` only
- `(s_2)` only
- `(s_1)` and `(s_2)`

Which strategy you choose should depend on the considerations listed above, combined with testing and benchmarking with the most realistic data you can generate.

With regards to the `or` operator in your query predicate, this *sometimes* means that only the leading column of the index (i.e. `s_1`) will be used to access the index, followed by a filter on the other column(s). However, it is also possible for the optimizer to split the query plan into two, one for each "side" of the OR predicate, followed by a concatenation - and each of these sides may take advantage of the same or different indexes.

Therefore, another potential indexing strategy to consider is `(s_1, s_2)` and `(s_1, s_2, s_3)`, or perhaps just `(s_1, s_2, s_3)` (a query on `s_1` and `s_2` might still take advantage of the latter index).